# Using button tags with variable in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

For each of my buttons I am doing the same methods but using a different variable from my array, this does work fine but its a lot of code and I will have around 40 buttons by the end. I was wondering if I could use the button tag to match with the `objectAtIndex` in my array, so I will not need to re-write for each tag,  Hope this question makes sense, below is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)pressCountBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int btag = btn.tag;

    if(btag == 1)
    {
        self.presscount1 ++;

        [self.pressCountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount1]];
        if (self.presscount1 > 3) 
        {
           self.presscount1 = 0;
           [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
           [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.presscount1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else if (btag == 2)
    {
        self.presscount2 ++;

        [self.pressCountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount2]];
         if (self.presscount2 > 3) 
         {
             self.presscount2 = 0;
            [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
        else
            [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.presscount2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

   else if (btag == 3)
   {
        self.presscount3 ++;

        [self.pressCountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount3]];
        if (self.presscount3 > 3) {
        self.presscount3 = 0;
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.presscount3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Yes you can do that. By the way you store the value in the array before you check for >3 and reset to 0. Is that what you intended?

Comment: yes that it what i wanted, i am doing things with the press count when it it at 1, 2 and 3 so wanted to store it back in the array.  Do you know how i would go about shortening my code please? would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressCountBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int btag = btn.tag;

    int curCnt = [[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:btag] intValue];
    curCnt ++;

    if (curCnt > 3) 
    {
       curCnt = 0;
       [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
       [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",curCnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

 [self.pressCountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:btag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curCnt]];

}
```

You'll just have to make sure that all objects in `self.pressCountArray` are NSNumbers, which you can easily do when you initialize the array.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the button index from an array of buttons is easy.

```
- (IBAction)pressCountBtn:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *thisButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSUInteger indexOfButton = [yourButtonArray indexOfObject:thisButton];
        if (indexOfButton != NSNotFound) {
            // Now use this indexOfButton for whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a strong array to hold the values(count) for each button tag.

```
NSInteger numberOfRows=3;
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfRows];
```

Then ,

```
- (IBAction)pressCountBtn:(id)sender
{
UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int btag = btn.tag;

    //add count first time for tag
   if([[array objectAtIndex:btag] valueForKey:@"COUNT"]==NULL){
        [[array objectAtIndex:btag] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"COUNT"];

    }else{
        //get count from array
         NSInteger count=[[[array objectAtIndex:btag] valueForKey:@"COUNT"] integerValue];

                count+=count;
                    if (count> 3)
            {
                count = 0;
                [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
                [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //write the updated count back to array
        [[array objectAtIndex:btag] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count] forKey:@"COUNT"];

    }
}
```